# Input text into a website with a batch file

Tags: html, web, input, batch-file, restart

I have a batch file that can open a website gooogle chrome, but now i need it to Select a Box titled Ip: and another titled Port: then have it select Restart on a drop down menu, after that i need to have it click a button saying enter. any ideas on how i should do this?

Comment: Have you looked into using Selenium?  It's slightly more setup (which I can easily help you with) for a nominal point fee :-)  but I don't know if it's worth the effort for what you're trying to do.  What is this for?  Is the return worth the investment of 30 minutes of your time?

Answer (score 0):

As seems as if you are trying to make a batch submit an online form. 
If this is the case, I recommend a different approach:
You could simply call the "submit.php" (name might be different) the form is posted to (via `METHOD: POST`) with the proper parameter strings.

Comment: Er... submit with a batch file using POST? Are you sure it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Which tools you are using in your batch file?
Are you are using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) ?
Maybe you can use it for you purpose. Its a powerful command line tool.